# Sequence-depedent calculation on SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a silo where I buy material from different suppliers (each time I do this, the added material has a lot number associated) and mix them inside. Then I consume mixed material from this silo.

I want to be able to calculate the proportion existing on the silo at any given moment with SQL.

I know how to do this with sequential programming but it must be a way to do this in SQL.

The table I have is a historic of movements, containing all necessary information for the calculations:

- ID
- Date
- Lot number (only relevant if it's a buy)
- Movement type (buy (1) or consumption (0))
- Quantity

Here it is a SQL fiddle for testing: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4ca50/1

In this example, the initial movement is a buy of 10.000 of lot 1000, then a consumption of 1.000 (so 9.000 remaining) and then another buy of 5.000 units of lot 2000.

Now, If I run the desired query up to that moment, it should return:

Lot 1000: 9.000 units (64,29%)

Lot 2000: 5.000 units (35,71%)

Next there are two consumptions for a total of 4.000 units, so at that point in the silo there a 10.000 remaining.

If I run the query until then, it should keep the same percentage but different amounts:

Lot 1000: 6.429 units (64,29%)

Lot 2000: 3.571 units (35,71%)

Then another buy of 8.000 units of lot 3.000, there are 18.000 total in the silo, so expected output is:

Lot 1000: 6.429 units (35,71%)

Lot 2000: 3.571 units (19,83%)

Lot 3000: 8.000 units (44,44%)

And finally after the last consuption of 2.000 there are 16.000 remaining in the same percentage:

Lot 1000: 5.715 units (35,71%)

Lot 2000: 3.173 units (19,83%)

Lot 3000: 7.112 units (44,44%)

I expect that you got the idea... basically each buy changes the composition in percentage, and each consumption keeps proportion but changes quantity.

I don't know where even to begin with the query... maybe it isn't even doable in pure SQL?